# Run Visual Studio Code on ARM Chromebook

Tags: arm, visual-studio-code, chromebook

On page:
https://code.headmelted.com/
there is a manual on how to install VSCODE on arm chromebook.

But after entering:

```
. <(wget -O - https://code.headmelted.com/installers/chromebook.sh)
```

And after installation - Appears in the console only:

```
crosh>
```

How can I start VSCODE now?